# How to draw rounded corner form in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Its not duplicate, please read the question properly and mark duplicate

I want to draw a rounded corner winform using C#.

I am able to draw it, but its not drawing border on corner.

I have used the below code.

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

            Pen DrawPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            GraphicsPath gfxPath_mod = new GraphicsPath();

            int top = 0;
            int left = 0;
            int right = Width;
            int bottom = Height;
            int CornerRadius = 18;

            gfxPath_mod.AddArc(left, top, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
            gfxPath_mod.AddArc(right - CornerRadius, top, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
            gfxPath_mod.AddArc(right - CornerRadius, bottom - CornerRadius, 
                    CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
            gfxPath_mod.AddArc(left, bottom - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);

            e.Graphics.DrawArc(DrawPen, left, top, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(DrawPen, right - CornerRadius, top, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(DrawPen, right - CornerRadius, bottom - CornerRadius, 
                    CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(DrawPen, left, bottom - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
            gfxPath_mod.CloseAllFigures();

            e.Graphics.DrawPath(DrawPen, gfxPath_mod);           

            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gfxPath_mod);
    }
```

Comment: What does `its not drawing border on corner.` means??

Comment: its giving the Arc shape to form but, border line is missing. I tried to draw with DrawArc method. but its not working.

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate. There is a wealth of information there on techniques for drawing rounded rectangles in Winforms code.

Comment: Well, the question has been closed with an irrelevant reference so I could not add my answer. I answer here, then. So, it you define a `Region`, it will just add a visibility mask to your control but will not change the windows theme rendering. So this is what you need to do: set `BorderStyle.None` for your form and draw some custom rounded border with some `Pen` using your `gfxPath_mod`.

Comment: its not duplicate, please read my question carefully. that post was for button control and in VB.net. For button and form things are different. I have implemented the rounded corner button already, but this time i want to implement it for form. just to increase your reputation value, dont do this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Can you review to make sure that the question is really a duplicate? It has been flagged for reopening.

Comment: I'm just continuing my previous answer: your `DrawPath` has two problems: firstly, if it is not inside of the original border (when `FormBorderStyle` is not `None`), then it  belongs to the so-called non-client area, which you cannot change in `OnPaint`. That's why you must use a borderless form. Secondly, try to use a thicker `Pen`; otherwise, it is possible that it will not be visible.

Comment: And thirdly, do not re-set the `Region` on every `OnPaint`. You can do it when you initialize your form. The `Region` object holds unmanaged resources do you should dispose it when the form is disposed.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: FYI: the marked duplicate involves drawing a rounded rect into a Winforms `Graphics` object using the `GraphicsPath` class. That the other question uses VB.NET is immaterial, especially given that one of the more useful answers there is in C# -- VB.NET and C# use the exact same .NET APIs. The OP here claims the other question is about buttons, but the word "button" only appears twice, in the code of one answer, and doesn't invalidate the usefulness of that answer for non-button scenarios.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Frankly, this question fails on other metrics too: lack of evidence of research, lack of a MCVE, lack of a clearly-stated problem statement. But it _also_ is a duplicate of the other question. The title (the clearest part of this question) asks "How to draw rounded corner form in winform", and the other question answers that quite well.

Comment: @Vivek: _"just to increase your reputation value"_ -- FYI: there is no reputation, or any benefit at all to me, for closing a question as a duplicate. Frankly, it's a pain in the neck to do so, because I have to go do the same research an OP should have in the first place. That said, I'm perfectly fine if you find a moderator, or gold badge, or five other people, to reopen the question. Reasonable people can have reasonable disagreements. But as far as I'm concerned, given the information you've provided in your post, your answer is in the other Q&A.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Though there is no screenshot, I think this is the problem of the OP, and not the accuracy of the corners without antialising: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0c4yL.png

Comment: @taffer: maybe it is; it's not at all clear to me from the question. If the OP is having problems with the area outside the intended form boundary, there are other duplicates to use, if you prefer. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25307970, http://stackoverflow.com/q/176720, to name a couple. On of the problems with posting such a broad, poorly stated question is that it can potentially be a duplicate of many other questions. The OP may want to follow the advice in the Help Center: post a new question, and be careful to provide the needed information to make it _clear_ it's not a duplicate.